# How to create a zip file using shell script?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, zip

I want to create a zip files based on the directory. But I need to make zip file from Result directory.

```
#!/bin/bash
zip -r /home/admin/download.zip /home/admin/1/2/3/Results
```

Comment: What is the problem/error you are facing? Please be elaborate when you ask question.

Comment: @user1984289 i like this structure 
download.zip
    |
     _ files (result directory files)

but now

download.zip
     |
      _home
        |
         _admin
           |
            _1
             |
              _2
               |
                _3
                 |_files (Result directories)

Comment: @javasundaram - your comment makes no sense

Comment: @EdHeal i like this format man download.zip->file(Result directory) but now, download.zip->home/admin/1/2/3/file(Result directory)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

From your question, I understand that you want to zip the files in the "Results" directory without considering the directory "Results" itself when trying to zip.

If so, then use the below commands

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/admin/1/2/3/Results
zip -r /home/admin/download.zip ./*
```

After this, the zip file would be created in the required location. Zip file is with only the files from the result directory, without the "Result" directory itself.

Comment: @Santhosh A i'm trying to implement same code in project it's not working.

Comment: @javasundaram I tried it myself on a folder, it is working. Check for any other possible issues

Comment: @Santhosh i tried this one

cd $MCELL_GENERATION_BASE_DIR/$uniqueid/$scenario_name/BWSIM/ >> $DBG_FILE 2>&1
    cp $SCRIPTS_EXE_BASE_DIR/$version/$SIM_EXE $MCELL_GENERATION_BASE_DIR/$uniqueid/$scenario_name/BWSIM/ 
    cp $SCRIPTS_EXE_BASE_DIR/$version/$WRAP_EXE $MCELL_GENERATION_BASE_DIR/$uniqueid/$scenario_name/BWSIM/ 
    cd $MCELL_GENERATION_BASE_DIR/$uniqueid/$scenario_name/BWSIM/Results/
    zip -r $MCELL_GENERATION_BASE_DIR/$uniqueid/$scenario_name/BWSIM/dnldtopology.zip ./*

Comment: Try with only these two commands                                        cd $MCELL_GENERATION_BASE_DIR/$uniqueid/$scenario_name/BWSIM/Results/ zip -r $MCELL_GENERATION_BASE_DIR/$uniqueid/$scenario_name/BWSIM/dnldtopology.zip ./*

Comment: @Santhosh A i need result directory files only make zip but it take outside result directory

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63918/discussion-between-santosh-a-and-javasundaram).